# VBA: Convert populated cells in columns to hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a SQL script as a data connection in Excel that essentially returns 3 columns. These 3 columns are all the text of hyperlinks. These 3 columns can contain nulls / empty cells.

I found a VBA script to run that converts these hyperlink texts into actual hyperlinks (as in you can click on the cell and it will take you to the webpage).

**My problem is:** The VBA script is converting empty / null cells into hyperlinks as well (that of course go nowhere, i.e., you click on the cell and it simply does nothing).

**My question is:** How do I edit this script to only convert non-empty / populated cells into hyperlinks?

**Script so far:**

```
Sub HyperlinkConverter()
For Each xCell In Range("M:O")
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
Next xCell
End Sub
```

**Pseudo-script:**

```
Sub HyperlinkConverter()
For Each xCell In Range("M:O") **WHERE RANGE("M:O") IS NOT NULL (or) RANGE("M:O") <> ""**
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
Next xCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test each cell:

```
Sub HyperlinkConverter()
   For Each xCell In Range("M:O")
      If xCell.Value <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
      End If
   Next xCell
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid the first row:

```
Sub HyperlinkConverter()
   For Each xCell In Range("M:O")
      If xCell.Value <> "" And xCell.Row <> 1 Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
      End If
   Next xCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect...I wish it was so simple for me as well. Thank you much, will accept in...9 minutes. Thanks Gary's.

Comment: Can I make one more request? What if I wanted to add to the If-Then the additional criterion that the cell that is being turned into a hyperlink if it is not null is ALSO not in row 1? As in I am mistakenly converting my headers into hyperlinks as well.

Comment: @Chase  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Wow, I will know that the next time now. Thank you very much. Answer accepted!